# BeautifulSoup4 data extract from HTML5 data-* tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract just the inner text **24,000.00** from the following tag:

```
<span class="itm-price mrs  ">
     <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span> 
     <span dir="ltr" data-price="24000">24,000.00</span> 
</span>
```

There are many similar tag like this in the page from where I want to extract data.

I'm trying to do this:

```
    for price in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'itm-price'}):
        item_price = price.get('data-price')
        print(item_price)
```

But Output is coming : `None`

I learned from the `Bs4 doc` that for html5 `data-*` tag we should use :

```
data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
# [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
```

As I'm very newbie here so I'm still unable to bring resutls using the method.

Comment: Do you want `24,000.00` (the inner text) or `24000` (which is _actually_ from the tag, more specifically the data attribute). Also, why aren't you actually using the code from the documentation you suggest?

Comment: try using 'item_price = price[data-price']' in the inner loop. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I want the inner text `24,000.00` and I tried the code from the documentation, but nothings happening as I'm surely doing some mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why look for the surrounding `<span>` when you can directly access the ones you want? Also, you can use keyword arguments (though I understand why you wouldn't want to try that with the `class` attribute, given that it's a Python keyword).

The `get_test()` method will extract the content from between a matching pair of tags, so you end up with quite a simple program:

```
# coding=utf-8
data = u"""\
<span class="itm-price mrs  ">
     <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span>
     <span dir="ltr" data-price="24000">24,000.00</span>
</span>
"""

import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
for price in soup.find_all('span', dir="ltr"):
    print(price.get_text())
```

Comment: Just wow and mind blowing. Thanks a lot sir, it worked. but **the loop is running like forever, it's not stopping after extracting my desired data.**

Comment: Try using `find()` instead of `findall`? I only tested it with your input, I don't know what your actual data looks like. With `find` you won't need a loop, if the first one is what you want to find

Comment: I have many similar tags in the web page from where I want to extract the data, exactly the same I posted above but with different `data-price` value and `inner-text`. _So I just want to gather all those `inner-text` which worked with your code_ but it's not stopping after getting what I want, instead outputting the same result again and again.

Comment: When you say "the loop is running like forever" do you mean the loop starting `for price in soup.find_all('span', dir="ltr"):` or some other loop you haven't shown?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html_doc = """
... <span class="itm-price mrs  ">
...      <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span> 
...      <span dir="ltr" data-price="24000">24,000.00</span> 
... </span>
... <span class="itm-price mrs  ">
...      <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span> 
...      <span dir="ltr" data-price="25000">25,000.00</span> 
... </span>
... <span class="itm-price mrs  ">
...     <span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span> 
...     <span dir="ltr" data-price="blabla">blabla</span> 
... </span>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find("span", dir="ltr").attrs['data-price']

# You can loop over

>>> for price_span in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"dir": "ltr", "data-price": re.compile(r"\d+")}):
...     print(price_span.attrs.get("data-price", None))

# output
24000
25000
```

Comment: I have many similar tags in the web page from where I want to extract the data.

Comment: Yes, same as I posted :)

Comment: Yes, it also worked but same problem, **the loop goes on. After getting the desired data, it continues to output the same data again and again.** Any way to stop after getting desired data?

Comment: @s4dman take a look at the updated code. you can use **regular expression**. Hope its gonna solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use find method:

```
>>>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>url="""<span class="itm-price mrs  "><span data-currency-iso="BDT">৳</span><span dir="ltr" data-price="24000">24,000.00</span></span>"""
>>>soup.find("span",dir="ltr").string
'24,000.00'
```

Comment: I have many tags like this from where I need to extract the inner value. I think `find` method is not gonna work. Anything more you can help me with? :)